# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing error in XAMPP 7.0.6

Tags: php, mysql, dll

I install latest version of XAMPP 7.0.6 but when I start Apache it shows httpd.exe error. I am using widows 7 32 bit on my laptop. Please tell me how to solve this error.

Thank You in advance

**See Error Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) perhaps not installed. Make a clean uninstall of xamp, then install Visual c++ 2010,2012/13 and finally the latest one. After that, try reinstalling xamp.